# Iterating through a list of objects and get one index of all objects to a Total

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I need to make a loop that iterates through all objects in the list and extracting the value of a specific index and return an Int with the total amount.
I will try to explain as throughly as possible.

```
public class CostEachActivity
{
    public string activityID { get; set; }
    public int accountNr { get; set; }       
    public int amount { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class which the list contains objects from.
I will send down a string of `activityID` which I have to return the total cost of from all accounts.

this is the list which contains all the objects(the count is 5 atm)

```
List<CostEachActivity> dka = new List<CostEachActivity>();
```

EDIT: This is the working method.

```
   int sum = 0;
List<CostEachActivity> templist = new List<CostEachActivity>();           
 foreach (CostEachActivity cea in dka)
 {
   if (cea.activityID == activityID)
       templist.Add(cea);
  }

foreach(var item in tempList)
 {
    sum += item.Amount;
 }
```

Comment: What is going on in the closure in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem

Your inner loop, besides not compiling, should be **outside the main loop**. After finding all the items you want to sum it (or in a different way to already sum it as you find the matching item.

Also, seeing that you opened a `{}` after the `if` and nested the second `foreach` in it - That scope happens for every item. You `if` statement, if returns `true` will execute the adding to the `tempList` and then, no matter what occurred in the `if` the second `foreach` will take place.

```
if (cea.activityID == activityID)  // If this is true
    templist.Add(cea);             // Then this executes

{                                 // And this happens in any case
    foreach (cea.amount = sum + amount)
}
```

> Possible Solutions

1. Doing it the way you started:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   List<CostEachActivity> templist = new List<CostEachActivity>();           
   foreach (CostEachActivity cea in dka)
   {
       if (cea.activityID == activityID)
           templist.Add(cea);
   }

   foreach(var item in tempList)
   {
       sum += item.Amount;
   }
   ```
2. Sum the values as you go:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   foreach (CostEachActivity cea in dka)
   {
       if (cea.activityID == activityID)
           sum += cea.Amount;
   }
   ```
3. And IMO the best way: Using linq you can do this:

   ```
   var sum = dka.Where(item => item.activityID == activityID)
                .Sum(item => item.amount);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! cant believe every little detail matter with this! Was very near this solution  during the day. But thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If I got this right you could do something like:

```
public int GetSum(string activityId)
{
    return dka.Where(cea => cea.activityId == activityId).Sum(cea => cea.amount)
}
```

Or with the new C# 6.0 Expression-bodied function members:

```
public int GetSome(string activityId) => 
    dka.Where(cea => cea.activityId == activityId)
    .Sum(cea => cea.amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq

```
public int GetSum(string activityID)
{
    return dka.Where(d => d.activityID == activityID).Sum(d => d.amount);
}
```